# AppleScript: Edit a fully written script buy "whiting out" certain commands but leaving it in so you can remember it

Tags: macos, applescript, editing

I've compiled my first web crawler script with AppleScript and I'm at the point now where I've gained a lot of knowledge and tricks from what I've written. I want to parse down the script now and disable some things that I thought would be helpful (for example: I coded it so the script completely quits Excel after entering the data in some workbooks from web pages because I noticed when you didn't start Excel fresh running the code it would return an error. But now I have the script running every 15 minutes so I worry that I will be working in Excel on some forecasting or formatting and the script will run and kick me out of Excel while I'm working and interrupt me or worse, quit without the option of saving). I vaguely remember C++ coding there was the ability to mark some text with a certain character that disabled it from running in the environment but made it so you could still see the original code before editing out stuff you decided wasn't necessary. Is there a way to mark a certain statement with a symbol so that AppleScript doesn't run the commands? I haven't experimented at all but I don't know what to guess that would do it. I may be mistaken that you can blank out or "white out" text while leaving it in the original position, still readable and able to be put back in when you want it or left for you so you have a collection of all the research you put into the process of building a script for a project. Well I suppose I'll just wonder a while and find something else to burn hours on.

Comment: Most languages have 'comments'. In applescript, you make a single line a comment by beginning it with two hyphens, e.g. -- this is a comment. Alternatively, you can make a 'block' of text a comment by putting '(*' before it and '*)' after it. You can find details in the Language Guide at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_lexical_conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH214-SW8. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is something in engineering that we call feature toggles.  It's basically wrapping certain functionalities into feature-check, that you can enable/disable as desired. The features are named specifically for it's purpose/category, for example, PERF_TRACKING, PROJECT_BELL, or whichever name that makes sense to you that's easy to remember.

Comment: Yes. I finally figured it out. I knew the idea of it but didn't know how to word it to solve it myself with google. I don't understand @user3579815 answer completely yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In applescript there are three ways to "comment" out text in your code.

```
--A line beginning with two dashes is a comment.
```

```
#In applescript 2.+, the number sign also works as a comment symbol.
```

```
(*  Multi-line text
can be commented out
using these symbols.  *)
```